# Issue with htaccess url redirections

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess (apache) file that has the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule questionnaire/login questionnaire/login.php
RewriteRule questionnaire/logout questionnaire/logout.php
RewriteRule questionnaire/account questionnaire/account.php
RewriteRule questionnaire/reopen/id/[(^/]+)$ questionnaire/reopen_questionnaire.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule questionnaire/register questionnaire/register.php
RewriteRule questionnaire/registration questionnaire/registration.php
```

When I run my site it gives me the following error : The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

When I remove this line : `RewriteRule questionnaire/reopen/id/[(^/]+)$ questionnaire/reopen_questionnaire.php?id=$1 [L]`   it works fine, can someone tell me why please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not nesting your code properly:

```
RewriteRule questionnaire/reopen/id/[(^/]+)$ questionnaire/reopen_questionnaire.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule questionnaire/reopen/id/([^/]+)$ questionnaire/reopen_questionnaire.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Problem is around the brackts -> "( )"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
RewriteRule questionnaire/reopen/id/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ questionnaire/reopen_questionnaire.php?id=$1 [L]
```